# Cinema seating arrangement

Tags: java

I'm wondering if anyone can help me, Im trying to create a simple cinema seating arrangement, where the x's are seats take and the o's are free. Problem is I cant seem to get the 0's to start where the X's finish. I'm new to java so what you see is the extent of my ability so far. Thanks for any help you can give at all!

```
public class Exercise4iv {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        int seats, taken, available, i, k;

        seats = 50;
        taken = 28;
        available = seats - taken;
        i = 0;
        k = 0;
        while (i <= taken) {
            i++;
            System.out.print("\t X");
            if (i % 8 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        while (k <= available) {
            k++;
            System.out.print("\t O");
            if (k % 8 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future make sure you are following good coding style. You should read through http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (k % 8 == 0) {
```

if you change this to

```
if ((k+taken+1) % 8 == 0) {
```

then it should correctly know when to print a newline

Comment: If only cinema companies could do this too!

Comment: @user2988501 actually I had an off by one error. See the new code

Comment: @AngryDuck Some of them actually have a seating system when you buy your ticket. And the system won't let you buy a ticket if you've left exactly a single seat between you and the people next to you. This is so couples can always book seats if there's any left! However, for this particular system(in the question) it would suck. The first person to buy their ticket has to sit at the front left?

Comment: i <= taken should of been i < taken, so you were correct the first time haha! but thanks anyway, really appreciate it!

Comment: @Cruncher I know they have them quite clever with the whole 1 seat rule though, my history with these are that they are an easy system to implement but somehow the big companies always seem to double book seats ... oh well nv, back on topic your solution is good so ill upvote just because :p

Comment: @AngryDuck well there's a synchronization issue. When I was with my buddy, he started booking a seat, but before he paid it was showing as booked(so that I don't have to wait for him to finish, that wouldn't be fun). However, his payment failed, and mine went through leaving one seat between afterwards. Hooray for breaking production systems. But yes, back on topic. This was rather simple :) but there are other problems with the code not related directly to the question asked

Answer (score 0):

change second while loop to:

```
while( i<seats){
    i++;
    System.out.print("\t O");
    if(i%8==0) System.out.println();}
}
```

this way the variable k is not required